# How to get the latest year in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
sql = "select scn,name,imp_flg,cg_desc from"
                    +" (select  vesvoy.scn, vessel.name,'I' as imp_flg,cargotype.description as cg_desc  from vesvoy"
                    +" join vessel on vesvoy.vessel_id = vessel.id "
                    +" join vesvoy_mf on vesvoy.id = vesvoy_mf.id_1"
                    +" join mf_bl on vesvoy_mf.id_2 = mf_bl.id_1"
                    +" join bl on mf_bl.id_2 = bl.id "
                    +" join blitem on blitem.master_id = bl.id"
                    +" join cargotype on blitem.cg_type_id = cargotype.id"
                    + " where bl.inv_flg<>'1' and year(vesvoy.exp_arr_dt_tm) in year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) , year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-1"
                    +" union"
                    +" select   vesvoy.scn, vessel.name,'E' as imp_flg,cargotype.description as cg_desc"
                    +" from vesvoy"
                    +" join vessel on vesvoy.vessel_id = vessel.id "
                    +" join vesvoy_so on vesvoy.id = vesvoy_so.id_1"
                    +" join so_sso on vesvoy_so.id_2 = so_sso.id_1"
                    +" join sso on so_sso.id_2 = sso.id "
                    +" join ssoitem on ssoitem.master_id = sso.id"
                    +" join cargotype on ssoitem.cg_type_id = cargotype.id"
                    + " where sso.inv_flg<>'1' and  year(vesvoy.exp_arr_dt_tm) in year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) , year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-1) as a ";
```

I did the above query.

Error saying that

> An unexpected token "year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),year" was found following
>   "oy.exp_arr_dt_tm) in . Expected tokens may include . SQLSTATE=42601"

Comment: Tip: Although it may not matter for a query of this complexity, your `in` check for a date in the current or prior year will not benefit from an index on `exp_arr_dt_tm`. If you calculate the actual date range and check for `vesvoy.exp_arr_dt_tm >= @StartDate and vesvoy.exp_arr_dt_tm <= @EndDate` then it becomes [SARGABLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the parentheses for `IN`

```
sql = "select scn,name,imp_flg,cg_desc from"
                +" (select  vesvoy.scn, vessel.name,'I' as imp_flg,cargotype.description as cg_desc  from vesvoy"
                +" join vessel on vesvoy.vessel_id = vessel.id "
                +" join vesvoy_mf on vesvoy.id = vesvoy_mf.id_1"
                +" join mf_bl on vesvoy_mf.id_2 = mf_bl.id_1"
                +" join bl on mf_bl.id_2 = bl.id "
                +" join blitem on blitem.master_id = bl.id"
                +" join cargotype on blitem.cg_type_id = cargotype.id"
                + " where bl.inv_flg<>'1' and year(vesvoy.exp_arr_dt_tm) in (year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) , year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-1)"
                +" union"
                +" select   vesvoy.scn, vessel.name,'E' as imp_flg,cargotype.description as cg_desc"
                +" from vesvoy"
                +" join vessel on vesvoy.vessel_id = vessel.id "
                +" join vesvoy_so on vesvoy.id = vesvoy_so.id_1"
                +" join so_sso on vesvoy_so.id_2 = so_sso.id_1"
                +" join sso on so_sso.id_2 = sso.id "
                +" join ssoitem on ssoitem.master_id = sso.id"
                +" join cargotype on ssoitem.cg_type_id = cargotype.id"
                + " where sso.inv_flg<>'1' and  year(vesvoy.exp_arr_dt_tm) in (year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) , year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-1) as a"
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, the current datetime is called by GetDate(). Also, when using IN, the list needs to be enclosed in parentheses so it would look like

```
and year(vesvoy.exp_arr_dt_tm) in (year(GETDATE()) , year(GETDATE())-1)
```

Comment: You can use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in SQL Server